# "care to have done"

Tags: grammar

> He had fallen into the habit of suggesting mildly anything that he
>   wanted done, and writing orders he didn’t particularly care to **have**
>   obeyed.

I read this in a novel, I know the meaning of this sentence.

But I don't understand why did here use "have". Can the "have" be replaced with "be"?

> ... orders he didn’t care to be obeyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the verb is ["to **have** something done"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/have-something-done): He **had** these orders obeyed, he cared about **having** those orders obeyed, he didn't care **to have** those other orders obeyed.

You can't replace *have* with *be*, because then the structure would be completely different and wrong: "He *was* these orders obeyed"?   "He cared about *being* those orders obeyed"?  "He didn't care *to be* those other orders obeyed"?  Those don't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

A quick test...

replace orders & obeyed with coffee & warm, then test again...

> I like to have my coffee warm.
>
> I like to be my coffee warm.

Doesn't work.

Equally...

> I like to have my orders obeyed.
>
> I like to be my orders obeyed.

The way you phrased it sounds like you might be able to get away with it, but if you recast into the simplest terms, you see that it doesn't actually work.
You have orders obeyed like you have a haircut, or have a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

> You should **have your cough treated** by a doctor.  It sounds bad.
>   --At the moment, I lack the money **to have it treated**.
>   Perhaps a neighborhood clinic would treat your cough at a lower cost?

or

> Class, I would **have you listen** carefully to the following sound. Can you identify the animal that is making this sound?